# Google spreadsheets api - export all sheets as csv

Tags: java, google-drive-api, export, spreadsheet

I use google drive api to export files from drive.google.com:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev201-1.21.0'
```

The way it's used:

```
Map<String, String> exportLinks = gFile.getExportLinks();
String exportLink =
exportLinks.get("application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet");
```

I'd like to download spreadsheets as csv instead of ods, but if I use

```
String exportLink = exportLinks.get("text/csv");
```

It downloads only the first sheet. I could specify sheet if I knew its' gids. How can I get links for all the pages?

Comment: you need to add Covert=true some place.    I don't have the power of java but it should be some were on the get method I would think.   assuming you are using Googles java client library.

Comment: While not a solution, you can use [this appscript](https://gist.github.com/mderazon/9655893) to make something similar in Java. The question is more related to Sheets API for me though , so looping thru the sheets can help you get the `gid` that you can use to export it.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to use Google Sheets and that's what helped:

```
compile (group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-sheets', version: 'v4-rev25-1.22.0')
compile (group: 'com.google.gdata', name: 'core', version: '1.47.1')

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets,
                    Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE, SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY))
                    .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
Credential credential = flow.loadCredential(userId);
Sheets sheets = new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
List<Sheets> sheetsList = sheets.spreadsheets().get("mySpreadsheetId").execute().getSheets();
for (Sheet sh : sheetList) {
    sout(sh.getProperties().getSheetId());
}
```

And the properties contain sheets gids.

Comment: Check question before writing something, irrelevant answer